# I want to call php function without refreshing page and return html

Tags: php, ajax

> this code is about showing more data from database within the same page,without refreshing page,but this deos not work.need some help.

```
 function showmore()
 {
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'showmore.php',
       data:{action:'true'},
       success:function(html) {
         alert(html);
       }

  });

 }

 <button type="button" onclick="showmore()">showmore</button>

showmore.php
<?php echo "<div><p>something</p></div>"?>
```

Comment: What "does not work"? What are you expecting? Where is your php code? Any errors?

Comment: no error at all, i want to display the echo of showmore.php at the current page

Comment: Modify your `success()` function to inert the returned html into your document.

Comment: how? im newbie..i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this to update your page dynamically:

In the php function:

```
<?php echo 'something'; ?>
```

Add this line to your html document (it is good practice not to return html from the server):

```
<div><p id="the-p-id"></p></div>
```

And in your jquery function, on success:

```
success: function(result) {
            $('#the-p-id').html(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me. If I use `library` of `jquery` like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function showmore(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'showmore.php',
            data:{action:'true'},
            success:function(html) {
                console.log(html);
            }

        });

    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="showmore()">showmore</button>

**showmore.php**

<?php echo "<div><p>something</p></div>"?>
```

**Output**

```
<div><p>something</p></div>
```